# Christoffel Symbols - Showing Equality

Tags: differential-geometry

Using: $$\sum_{j} g_{ij}g^{jk}=\delta_i^k$$
$$\Gamma_{ijk}+\Gamma_{jik}=\frac{\delta g_{ij}}{\delta u^k}$$
$$\Gamma_i{^j}_k = \Gamma_k{^j}_i = \sum_{l} g^{jl}\Gamma_{ilk}$$

Show that: $$g_{11}\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_1{^1}_2+g_{12}\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_1{^2}_2 = \frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_{112}-(\Gamma_1{^1}_2(\Gamma_{111}+\Gamma_{111})+\Gamma_1{^2}_2(\Gamma_{211}+\Gamma_{121})$$

I should preface this by saying that I have played around with the equations suggested to use and keep running into dead ends. I've had false starts from the left and the right side of the equation. I cannot determine the cleanest start.

Also, this is for an introductory math course on curves and surfaces - we have not related any of the work we've done with Christoffel symbols to spherical coordinates, nor physics. A lot of the research I've found on similar problems has been physics related, which is pretty over my head.

Can anyone give me a gentle suggestion on where to start? I feel like if I get started down the right path, it will unfold relatively easily though so far it looks tedious.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of $\Gamma_{ijk}$? Is it the same as $\Gamma_{ij}^k$?

Comment: No, I don't think so. What I have from my notes are: $$\Gamma_{ijk}=\sum_{l} g_{jl}\Gamma_i{^l}_k$$ and $$\Gamma_i{^j}_k=\sum_{k} g^{kl}\Gamma_{ilj}$$

And when we went over it in class, professor mentioned that this was necessary to translate them back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really algebraic manipulation and has nothing to do with differential geoemtry. You may write

$${{\Gamma_{1}}^1}_2 = \sum_{j}g^{1j}\Gamma_{1j2}$$

and then use product rule to derive the right hand side. But that would be a huge mess I suppose. It will be easier to do the product rule in advance:

$$\begin{split} 
g_{11}\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_1{^1}_2+g_{12}\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_1{^2}_2 &=\sum_k g_{1k}\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\Gamma_1{^k}_2 \\
&= \frac{\delta}{\delta u}\left(\sum_k g_{1k}\Gamma_1{^k}_2\right) - \sum_k \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta u} g_{1k}\right) \Gamma_1{^k}_2
\end{split}$$

The first term gives you $\frac{\delta}{\delta u} \Gamma_{112}$ and together with the second equation (since $u = u^1$), you are done.

Comment: Thank you - I am about neck deep in the huge mess part of the product rule, so I appreciate knowing I was at least headed in the right direction. I appreciate your quick response!!!